# Slim 3 get host url

Tags: url, slim-3

In Slim 3, this command...

```
  print_r($request->getUri() );
```

Returns this list...

```
Slim\Http\Uri Object
(
    [scheme:protected] => http
    [user:protected] => 
    [password:protected] => 
    [host:protected] => slimtree.test
    [port:protected] => 80
    [basePath:protected] => 
    [path:protected] => /
    [query:protected] => 
    [fragment:protected] => 
)
```

Well enough.

I've read every Slim URL-related question on SO, a few never answered the question, but I can't find the answer.

There must be a better way to get the host base path than this...

```
 $hostUrl = $request->getUri()->getScheme() . '://'
          . $request->getUri()->getHost()
          .($request->getUri()->getPort() ? ':' . $request->getUri()->getPort() : '')
 ;
```

To get this...

```
http[s]://myDomain.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get base URL, you can call `getBaseUrl()` method from `Uri` class. To get full url, you can typecast `Uri` class as string.

```
$uri = $request->getUri();
$baseUrl = $uri->getBaseUrl();
$fullUrl = (string) $uri;
```

`Uri` class implements PSR-7 [`UriInterface`](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/#35-psrhttpmessageuriinterface) so it implements `__toString()` method that is called when `Uri` instance is typecasted to string.